# My website doesn't look good on my local webserver on ie8 & ie11, but it looks good on google chrome

Tags: iis-7, web, webserver, servermanager

My other issue is that I am trying to run it in my local webserver (Window Server 2008), and the website seems to have a problem with IIS7 I guess because when I run it on iE (8 & 11), the menu doesn’t look good, and the slider too, but when I run it on google chrome, in my local webserver, the problem goes away. Do you think it would be any solution to work something around it, because I need to run it in ie. I tried hosting it with goddady and doesn’t seem to have any of these problems. Any advice is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Javascript is an option you could use the modernizr library.

It backports the modern html and css that you are using to work on older browsers.

Without you posting any code or detailing your server configuration that's about all the advice that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

When I run it on **Internet Explorer** my navigation bar, doesn't work properly and some other elements do not show. But with **google chrome** everything works good. In the beginning I thought it was a browser issue so I hosted with **Goddady** and it worked perfectly with **ie8 - ie11**. So it doesn't make it a browser issues, it something between **ISS7 & Internet Explorer** (because even with ie11 doesn't work). Thanks